# Error when using calendar from external library

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to use this calendar for my vue app
https://litepicker.com/#usage

In my component

```html
<input type="text" id="litepicker">
```

```js
import Litepicker from 'litepicker';
new Litepicker({ 
    element: document.getElementById('litepicker') 
  });
```

I also tried it in setup() with a `ref` instead of grabbing element by id. With both tries I am getting this error:

[image]

Is this calendar not suitable for vue, or I am just doing something wrong?

Comment: It is always tricky to integrate pure JS libraries into a framework. But you could try to initialize it on `mounted` because before the element wont be available in the DOM. Same with ref, the ref will be null until the component is mounted.

Comment: @Thomas thank you, somehow it worked with mounted.